# Why I get a strange conflit when doing git rebase

Tags: git

All:

My commit log is like:

```
commit 1e17b836cce12d497ef86e5b2c45410c93caf3a2
    add 4
commit cbf7e720313ef6c918a8d4117df007eabe2ef92b
    add 3
commit 951f86964102e17cdf3e3c2978c1adf8d5cdfab7
    add 2
commit a275ad4e6716b950d86ce8885d766bba803fc9e0
    add 1
commit d14904ad7fa9142cbc38489d1d621d1a157aa0cd
    init commit
```

Basically, init commit is a blank file, and each commit I add one line with according number. Now, say I want to remove that `add 2` operation but keep others, someone told me I should use `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

The rebase shows me a history to modify, I change it to:

```
drop 951f869 add2
pick cbf7e72 add3
pick 1e17b83 add4
```

And save it. Then I got a conflict error:

```
error: could not apply cbf7e72... add3

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Then I use git diff to check where is conflict, I got :

```
diff --cc test
index 56a6051,5f5fbe7..0000000
--- a/test
+++ b/test
@@@ -1,1 -1,3 +1,7 @@@
- 1
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++1
++=======
+ 1
+ 2
 -3
++3
++>>>>>>> cbf7e72... add3
```

My question here is:

**How this conflict get calculated out? Where is my line of 4? This rebase conflict totally ruins the content and not indicates correct diff which I have no way to resolve the correct content out based on current conflict file.**

So what is the correct way to this? A step by step example with result output will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to explain if we use some text in the lines of code.  I'll just create a file with each commit adding a new line with the corresponding commit.  e.g.

final file looks like this:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

Then when I do the interactive rebase, I'll get this prompt:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
First Line
=======
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
>>>>>>> 8ba3272... Added Third Line
```

Everything above ============= is the original, and everything after was the state after the third commit.  There is a merge conflict because it's trying to add a line to the third line, and there isn't one yet.  So this is where you would need to resolve the conflict.  If you want the output to be:

```
First Line
Third Line
```

You would just need to delete the <<<<<<< and >>>>>>>>>>>>>> markers and enter how you would want the file to look, then do a `git add` then `git rebase --continue`.

Then it would try to add the 4th commit, and you'd get *another* merge conflict because it's trying to add a fourth line.  So you'd just need to resolve that conflict in the same way.  Followed by another `git rebase --continue` to finish the interactive rebase.

The final file should look like this:

```
First Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

and the `git log` would show this (the commit adding the second line has been removed):

```
commit 9064bd9d9efece49c0cf2dacd41be98e8cb70d01
Author: Kief Kraken
Date:   Thu Sep 29 11:05:44 2016 -0700

    Added fourth Line

commit cdcd1a33fb7b41e583fdb8098b266b0fb6898aca
Author: Kief Kraken
Date:   Thu Sep 29 11:05:21 2016 -0700

    Added Third Line

commit 7744551b481d4c6f7f5da038c56f3044d8b000d2
Author: Kief Kraken
Date:   Thu Sep 29 10:52:20 2016 -0700

    Added first line

commit e8e76881002e361401bbaaa22140660ed026fd04
Author: Kief Kraken
Date:   Thu Sep 29 10:51:56 2016 -0700

    first commit
```

While this is good for an exercise learning about interactive rebasing, I would strongly recommend using a merge tool that makes managing these tasks much easier and give less room for error.

Comment: Thanks. After I understand what is going on, I still get a little confused, take the first conflict for example: How do I know what that `add Third Line` commit should looks like without the change from `add Second Line`(say add second Line and add third line both done by others, our example is simple to tell, but in reality, it may be many places)

Answer (score 1):

You get the conflict while rebasing the commit `add3` onto the commit `add1`. At this point in history, there was no line 4. This will be added later when `add4` is rebased onto the rewritten commit `add3`.

As such, just fix your file to contain lines 1 and 3, then `git add` the result, and continue with `git rebase --continue`. I believe, you will get a similar conflict again, this time because the context of the introduction of line 4 has changed. Which can be resolved just as easily.

---

Btw: I strongly recommend using the `diff3`-style commit markers. They are enabled by

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

This will include a third version of the conflicted lines between the `=======` and `|||||||` which shows the state before the conflicting changes were introduced. This allows you to easily see what each side actually changed, allowing for a much more informed, and thus more likely correct conflict resolution.

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense now, but so complicated. Is there a simple way that I can know what should resolve if add3 is not done by me?

Comment: The complexity comes from the fact that you are working with different historic versions, and there is really no way of hiding this complexity. However, as I added in my commit, I find that using the diff3-style conflict markers makes it much easier to make the right choices when resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute:

```
git mergetool
```

It is expected that mergetool resolve the conflict "automagically". Then execute:

```
git rebase --continue
```

You're done.

Consider to install some graphical merge tool like "[kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)".